# In WatchOS, how to know in which language presentTextInputController is recognizing text?

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos

By Default WatchOS's presentTextInputController is recognizing in english language, we can change the recognizing language using deep touch.How to get the language code when user changes language using deep touch while recognizing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible at the moment. Looking at the documentation of WatchKit, there doesn't seem to be an API for this.
However, you can call `presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions(forLanguage:allowedInputMode:completion:)` if you want to specify what language you can handle. See the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1619574-presenttextinputcontrollerwithsu).

Comment: presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions(forLanguage:allowedInputMode:completion:) this method just take suggestion based on language and any time new language is detected it is called again